# Python urllib cannot open localhost

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, urllib

I use Python 3.4.2 on linux here's my code.

```
myurl = 'http://localhost/test.php'
response = urllib.urlopen(myurl) 

while response.text != 'exit':
    response = urllib.urlopen(myurl)
```

And i got this error

```
  Traceback (most recent call last) :

     File "/var/www/html/led.py", line 19, in <module>

        response = urllib.urlopen(myurl)

  AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'urlopen'
```

Comment: [`urllib.request.urlopen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html#module-urllib.request) in python 3

Answer (score 1):

In python 3 the module is `urllib.request.urlopen`. Use it as shown below-

```
import urllib.request
# and then 
response = urllib.request.urlopen(myurl)
```